# How to use gcp workload identity in java springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, workload-identity

In below I set the variable in application.properties and the tried using default service instance:

```
    private static void testListGCPBucket() String configPath) throws IOException {
        
         Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("completed...");
    }
```

**application.config** file content:

**GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**=classpath:config.json

But this is not working I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/proj-workload-id-svc-acct@idmp-mii-dev-ddb5.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1116)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ImpersonatedCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ImpersonatedCredentials.java:441)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: How is **Workload Identity Federation** related to your question? Your code is using ADC (Application Default Credentials). Those credentials do not have permission to access Cloud Storage. If you are federating credentials from AWS, Azure, or another OAuth provider, you will need to show that code, how those credentials are set up, the federated service account roles and a **redacted** credentials file. Edit your question to clarify and provide more information.

Comment: Are you talking about Workload Identity Federation or GKE Workload identity. And why do you need a JSON file? What is the format of this file?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, if using the *DefaultService* then it will look at your environment variables.   Setting it into your application.properties will not modify your environmental variables.

You will need to point to your file instead.  Adding it to your application.properties, *it will not be picked up.*

```
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
  .fromStream(new FileInputStream("yourJsonConfig"));
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Or according to the official documentation, you can use Spring Cloud GCP Starter, and configure it using your application.properties file.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/spring-cloud-gcp-core.html#_credentials

**2 Credentials**

> CredentialsProvider is a functional interface that returns the
> credentials to authenticate and authorize calls to Google Cloud Client
> Libraries.
>
> public interface CredentialsProvider {   Credentials getCredentials()
> throws IOException; }
>
> The Spring Cloud GCP starter auto-configures a CredentialsProvider. It
> uses the spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location property to locate the
> OAuth2 private key of a Google service account. Keep in mind this
> property is a Spring Resource, so the credentials file can be obtained
> from a number of different locations such as the file system,
> classpath, URL, etc. The next example specifies the credentials
> location property in the file system.
>
> spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/usr/local/key.json
>
> Alternatively, you can set the credentials by directly specifying the
> spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key property. The value should be
> the base64-encoded account private key in JSON format.
>
> If that credentials aren’t specified through properties, the starter
> tries to discover credentials from a number of places:
>
> ```
> Credentials file pointed to by the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
> Credentials provided by the Google Cloud SDK gcloud auth application-default login command
> Google App Engine built-in credentials
> Google Cloud Shell built-in credentials
> Google Compute Engine built-in credentials
> ```
>
> If your app is running on Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine,
> in most cases, you should omit the
> spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location property and, instead, let the
> Spring Cloud GCP Starter get the correct credentials for those
> environments. On App Engine Standard, the App Identity service account
> credentials are used, on App Engine Flexible, the Flexible service
> account credential are used and on Google Compute Engine, the Compute
> Engine Default Service Account is used.

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/usr/local/key.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am explicitly setting the GoogleCredentials by pointing it to the json file path. But now I am getting error **Failed to retrieve AWS region**.

Is there any way to get the AWS region for local machine instead of using below URL
"region_url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone"